# Installing Windows 1.04

Tags: windows, installation

I have Windows 1.04 on seven 5¼" disks, and I have a Dell from 2000 with a 5¼" floppy drive connected up.

Now with the first disk in, and with the BIOS set up to boot from A:, after the normal Dell loading screen the computer flashes up a message for a split second (not enough to read it) and goes into Windows XP normally.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the adventure continues, eh :) 
If you are fast enough, you can try to  press pause just when the message comes and post it here.

Comment: Ah, I had no idea the pause key did that - I was actually thinking of using some kind of 'print screen' at the time! I think I rewrote the first disk to see if another Windows version worked, so I don't think we'll ever know now..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Windows pre-NT runs on top of DOS. Install DOS first.

Comment: Thanks. Which version do you recommend?

Comment: I'd try FreeDOS first.

Comment: Apparantly Dos 3.3 works with it

Comment: @Mark no, NT predates all of those. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_Windows - also, DOS in those versions ran as an application (or sometimes a 'reboot into' option). There was no DOS underlying NT or its successors.